# Duplicate a View Android

Tags: android

I would like to clone a View, graphicaly and functionaly (event). For exemple I have a button on my RelativeView, I get it with findViewById(View) and copy the info inside another button, and finaly put it (the clone) on the relativeView. Like that I could have two buttons and when I click on the copy it triggers the same event. I already did clone = findViewById(View) but the app crash. I don't know if it's possible. I would like to know also if it could be possible to make a generic class. Because the view could be a button but also a Text or An Image. I want to know it's possible to avoid to make three differents methods. But if I have to copy info by info, i will need to make three methods.I'm a begginer in Android ;).

Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 1):

you are smart Sir, unfortunately that is the way to go though, quick tip when you are implementing `Button` extends `TextView` so can always call text functions on a `Button` like `View.setText("")`, so forget about it being Button or `TextView` and go for a `boolean` attack on `ImageView` or `TextView`

hope i am smart too

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to implement custom views which have the desired properties.

Then you can do this:

`LinearLayout myLayout = root.findViewByID(R.id.main);
CustomView myView = new CustomView(this);
myLayout.addView(myView);`